# Is it possible to configure the deployment region for Firebase Cloud Functions globally?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

It is possible to set the region to which Cloud Functions in Firebase will be deployed *on per function basis*: https://firebase.blog/posts/2018/08/cloud-functions-for-firebase-config-node-8-timeout-memory-region

Is it also possible to set it globally for all functions in my project (e.g. via `firebase.json`) or per set of functions (e.g. through something like

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

functions.setDefaultRegion('europe-west1')`

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore.[...]
```

)?

I did not find any information on that but it would be very useful for my use case to not have to write it for each function individually because it raises the risk of deploying to the wrong region.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#selecting-regions_firestore-storage) for firebase cloud functions there does not appear to be this ability to automatically do this. One could do the below.. I do mine this way as I could not find a working way that was better.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const region = 'REGION_NAME'

exports.FUNCTION_NAME = functions
    .region(region)
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would be my fallback but I had hoped for a solution that saves me the `.region()` because if I forget it, the function will be deployed to `us-central1` by default where I do not want to have it :-P

Comment: No worries, I would check GCP after deploying, will be very easy to see if there is a function deployed in the wrong region. Mark as complete to close the thread 

Answer (score 2):

### Python

When using Python for Firebase Functions, one can use [`set_global_options`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/python/firebase_functions.options#set_global_options).

Example for setting custom values for region, memory, and timeout:

```py
from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app
import firebase_functions.options as options

initialize_app()

options.set_global_options(region="europe-west3", memory=512, timeout_sec=90)


@https_fn.on_call()
def example_function(req: https_fn.CallableRequest):
    return "Hello world!"
```